# Update Model Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

While updating the model depending on the where clause, eloquent is unable to update the table.

Using DB::enableQueryLog(), I found the raw query and executed it on Mysql workbench, it works as expected.

The query is as mentioned below:

```
Model::where('uid', 'user1')
    ->update(['uid' => 'user2']);
```

It's simply not updating the field.

Comment: If the query works elsewhere, it sounds like you're using transactions without committing the changes.  Is this in a test?

Comment: Yes, i am using transactions but also commiting them. Also I am running one delete query and one update within a transaction. Delete query is working fine but update fails.

Comment: Did uid update to user2? If so, you won't find user1.

Comment: The problem is it is unable to update it.

Comment: You're going to need to show more code.

Comment: Is `uid` overriding the default primary key?  If so, as a non-numeric value you may need to add `public $incrementing = false;` and most recently in Laravel 6 `protected $keyType = 'string';` to your Model class.

Comment: Also, make sure the `uid` field is listed in the `$fillable` properties of your Model, or appropriate `$guarded` properties are set.  Again, if we could see your code, this would be a lot easier instead of guessing.